# Serve images in emails from http or https?

Tags: email, email-attachments, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

Does it make a difference at all whether I serve the images in an email campaign from an encrypted domain? Will this make emails less likely to end up in a client's spam folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference. Almost everyone uses `http://` without any spam hit, so there is nowhere for `https://` to improve on that, even though spam filters are an accumulative score.

If there was something in either your content or reputation flagging you as spam, having `https://` linked images wouldn't award you any 'bonus points' to save the day.

Comment: Thanks John for the crisp response!

Answer (score 8):

Using `http` insteadt of `https` will most likely not affect the spam/ham classification.

However, it could throw warnings in older browsers, which may confuse your recipients. The reason is because most webmail services - like Gmail, Outlook.com (former Hotmail), or Yahoo! Mail - default to SSL when the user logs in. Loading images from non-secure sources now is a possible security leak. [This blogpost](http://robinteractive.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/google-poisoning-email-marketing/) and the screenshot below illustrate the problem and the resulting browser behaviour.

Furthermore, you'll miss referrer information of a recipient who opened an email on `https`, when the tracking pixel is located just on `http`.

Finally, if you use `https`, make sure the certificate is valid and up-to-date. Otherwise email clients like Thunderbird throw warnings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I second @lukeA's answer and would like to stress that the impact of using images served over `http://` connections has certainly increased, even in web-based email clients.

See for example Google Inbox in Chrome (48.0.2564.109), before and after looking at an email which includes an image served over `http://` (in that case, a spam email). Note the green lock is gone until you refresh the page!

Gmail's [image proxy](https://support.google.com/mail?p=display_images) serves all images over `https://` - however, it is unclear (to me) for which images the proxy is really used. For that particular spam mail that I opened to create the below snapshots, it certainly isn't.

[image: before]

[image: after]